# Take a captured packet from Wireshark and spoof a copy?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I have a packet captured in Wireshark that I want to spoof and send an exact copy of. Same src, dst, ports, payload, flags, etc. Does anyone know what the best way to do this is?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [PlayCup](http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/).

[PlayCup](http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/) is a GUI tool for playing back pcap/Wireshark captures (GPL, Linux/Windows).

Comment: Thank you so much!